# Proguard vs Annotations

Tags: java, annotations, proguard

I have an app that uses ActiveAndroid, a database ORM library, that relies on annotations.

```
@Table(name="test")
public class DatabaseItem extends ActiveRecordBase<DatabaseItem> {

    public DatabaseItem(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Column(name="counter")
    public int counter;

}
```

How do I get Proguard working nicely with this? Currently, I get errors about not finding a column name by ActiveAndroid when using Proguard. I guess it somehow mangles the annotation.

My relevant Proguard configuration:

```
#ActiveAndroid
-keep public class com.activeandroid.**
-keep public class * extends com.activeandroid.ActiveRecordBase
-keepattributes Column
-keepattributes Table
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`Column` and `Table` aren't existing java class file attributes. You'll at least have to specify

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Cfr. the [ProGuard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#annotations).

Comment: Assuming that `Table` and `Column` are both attributes applied to a class, I would say at a minimum `-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations` needs to be applied. `*Annotation*` is overly inclusive, including annotations on parameters, type parameters, and runtime invisible annotations.

Answer (score 16):

In March 2013, [Proguard version 4.9 was released](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#downloads.html), one of the fixes were:

```
Fixed overly aggressive shrinking of class annotations.
```

So make sure that your Proguard version is up to date and then use Eric Lafortune's solution:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

You can also use this configuration to store all class members that has a specific annotation:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @fully.qualified.package.AnnotationType *;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Solution was to keep all members of the library and the database classes

```
-keep class com.activeandroid.**
{
     *;
}
-keep public class my.app.database.**
{
    *;
}
-keepattributes Column
-keepattributes Table
```

Comment: I used this, but instead of the two lines of "-keepattributes" I used this only line: "-keepattributes \*Annotation\*", as indicated by Eric Lafortune and Simon André Forsberg. Everything worked fine now!

Comment: "Column" and "Table" are invalid options for `-keepattributes`. You [can't pass annotation names to keep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69523469/590790).

Answer (score 2):

For those only using Gradle, the solution is very similar (note the single quotes around the Annotation):

```
keep 'public class java.package.** { *; }'

keepattributes '*Annotation*'
```

This is especially useful if you are using JSON serialization annotations (e.g., Jackson or the like) in a vanilla Gradle project.

Answer (score 0):

This what worked in my case:

```
-keep class com.activeandroid.** { *; }
-keep class com.activeandroid.**.** { *; }
-keep class * extends com.activeandroid.Model
-keep class * extends com.activeandroid.serializer.TypeSerializer
-keep public class * extends com.activeandroid.ActiveRecordBase

-keepattributes Column
-keepattributes Table
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclasseswithmembers class * { @com.activeandroid.annotation.Column <fields>; }
```

Comment: "Column" and "Table" are invalid options for `-keepattributes`. You [can't pass annotation names to keep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69523469/590790).